# Compare Current line and Previous line of the CSV File

Tags: java, xml, csv, marshalling, unmarshalling

I have a program i java and I need to transform my `CSV` file to `XML` file.the issue is that XSD can have multiple child.
This is the format of my `csv` file

```
User ID; Number; IPF;PointNumber; Length
37686;4851;2;0;127.9
37686;9978;2;0;0
37686;9994;2;0;0
11111;9994;2;0;0
```

This is the result that I need to get:

```
<Plant>
        <UserID>37686</UserID>
        <Verification>
            <Detail>
                <Number>4851</Number>
                <IPF>2</IPF>
            </Detail>
            <Detail>
                <Number>9978</Number>
                <IPF>2</IPF>
            </Detail>
            <Detail>
                <Number>9994</Number>
                <IPF>2</IPF>
            </Detail>
        </Verification>
        <PointNumber>0</PointNumber>
        <Length>127.9</Length>
</Plant>
```

Based on XSD Each  `UserID` can have more than one  `Detail`

So my requirment is to check each line of CSV to see if the  `UserID`  is the same or no.

```
String[] prevvalue = null;
 while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {   
                    
                    Start++;
                    String[] currentvalue;
                
                    String[] value =line.split(";");
                    
                     currentvalue =line.split(";");
                    System.out.println(Start);
                    Detail Detail = new Detail();
                    ArrayList<Detail> DetailList = new ArrayList();

                    Plant Plant = new Plant();   
                    if (Start >0 && prevvalue!= null) {
                        prevvalue = line.split(";") ;
                        if (currentvalue[0]!= prevvalue[0]) {
                            Plant.setUserID(currentvalue[0]);
                            Plant.setPointNumber(currentvalue[3]);
                            impianto.setLength(currentvalue[4]);
                            
                            Detail.setNumber(currentvalue[1]);
                            Detail.setIPF(currentvalue[2]); 
                        }
                        else if (currentvalue[0]== prevvalue[0]) {
                            
                            Detail.setNumber(currentvalue[1]);
                            Detail.setIPF(currentvalue[2]); 
                        }
                        
                    }
                DetailList.add(Detail);
                Plant.setDetail(Detaillist);
                PlantList.add(Plant) ;
```

I need to know how can I save the current line in another Array and Compare it with the next Line.

Can anyone suggest me a solution?

Thanks

Sin

Comment: Exactly as you said. You create a copy of your array in another variable, which is defined outside the while. In the first loop it will be null so you will have to check for that.

Comment: The issue is i can't do it outside while, because it is the end of reading and read all the rows.I need to have another for loop... I do not know how can I loop on each row... I mean I want to write a For loop , but I do not know how to define number of lines.

Comment: "Outside the while" means *before the while*.

Comment: In your example the XML is not valid. Opening and closing tag doesn't match, e.g. `<UserID>37686</idImpianto>`. And for the last row, do you want a new Plant element?

Comment: Yes vanje, I made mistakes in the XML. It is valid they had the same tag name. 
And as you said the last raw should be a new Plant element

Comment: Assuming your CSV file is ordered by user id and point number and length are always in the first row for each group then you need only one loop. For each new user id create the starting Plant tag and user id tag. Store point number and length for later use. For the current line and all next lines with same user id write the Detail elements. If you read the next line with a different user id, write the formerly stored point number and length elements at first. Then start at the beginning. After the last CSV row (after the loop) you has to write the last group's point number and length.

Comment: This is exactly what I am looking for... But My issue is with " For the current line and all next lines with same user id write the Detail elements. If you read the next line with a different user id..." I can not do a loop on rows... maybe I make a mistake in my code... But I can not achieve the loop on each row

Comment: You only have one loop. You have a variable declared outside of the loop to store user id for the current group. E.g. `lastUserId`. Inside at the loop you read the current row's user id. If this is different from `lastUserId` then this is the beginning of a new group.

Comment: Then you write the pending elements for the last group and set `lastUserId = currentUserId`.

Comment: If the last user id and the current are the same, you know that you are in the middle of a group and only have to write the Detail node.

Comment: You only process one CSV line at one loop iteration. But you treat them differently according to the current user id to last user id comparison.

Comment: I modified my question and insert my code... Could you please take a look at it to see where is the issue?